# Swift 2.0 and let warnings

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, let

I have a problem in swift 2.0

here is the current block of code that I write:

```
let URL = NSURL(string:"www.google.com")
```

and then I get the following warning:"initialization of immutable value URL was never used, consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

What should i do when I want to declare a let.

I get a similar warning when writing [image: var URL = NSURL(string: "www.google.com")]

What can I do in swift 2.0 to declare a Let or a var?

Comment: I think you are not using that `URL` object anywhere in your code, that's why swift throwing that warning. Actually I'm not seeing that warning with URL object, instead seeing that warning for data object !!! (From the screenshot)

Comment: If you are not using variable `data`, don't declare it.

Comment: You are not using `data` because you declare it but then it is re-declared as a parameter in the callback and that's what you're actually using.

Comment: Here is my current code: {       let URL = NSURL(string: "www.amazon.com")
        let data  = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(URL!)
            { (data, response, error) in
       
                if (error == nil){
                    let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print(urlContent)
                }
        }
    } and i still get the same error even though i replaced var with let

Answer (score 4):

> `initialization of immutable value URL was never used`

Means that you didn't use the variable anywhere, so its throwing a warning. But looking at the screenshot, you have declared `URL` as a `var` and used it in `data` which is another var.

So there should be two warnings now. `URL` is declared as a `var` but never mutated and `data` variable was never used.

To satisfy, use `let URL ...` since you are not mutating it. and do away with `data` as this is a async block/closure and you can access `data` from the completion block.

Note:

You should use `let` when you are not modifying it later and you should use `var` when you want to modify the object. Consider array :

```
let immutableArray:[String] = ["foo", "bar"]
var mutableArray:[String] = ["hello"]

mutableArray.append("World") // Is valid since its a var
immutableArray.append("abc") // Not valid, infact auto complete does not even show append methods
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are declaring a `let` and not using that constant complier will show a warning. There is nothing to worry about. If you are not using `let` constant replace it with `_`.  It is for optimization. If you are not using remove that let. Or to silence warning use a simple `print(YOUR Constant)`
For your case user

```
let url = URL = NSURL(string:"www.google.com")
```

Than

```
let data = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(URL!) {
{ (data, response, error) in {
  if(error != nil) {
  print(data) // This data is different from let data constant
}
print(data) // This will silence warning. Also make sure it is not nil
```

Answer (score 0):

this may work fine.

```
let URL = NSURL(string:"www.google.com")
NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(URL!) { (url: NSURL?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && url != nil {
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
            print(data)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `var` to `let` to resolve this warning.
To save memory, Compiler recommend user to use `let` instead of `var` when you only need to get value from a variable but not set